# Cartesian product table for an algebraic relation in R

Tags: r, relation, cartesian-product

I have one or two numerical vectors, e.g. `x <- c(1, 2, 3)`. I want to create a graphical representation of the relation `aRb`, where `R` is any algebraic formula such as `a + b` (used in the example below) or `a / (a + b)` (with `a,b` any element of `x`, including `a = b`, i.e. a reflexive relation).

The structure should be:

```
R   a   b   c
a  a+a a+b a+c
b  b+a b+b b+c
c  c+a c+b c+c
```

so the output would be (for the sample vector x above):

```
R   1   2   3
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
3   4   5   6
```

`R` can also be a comparison such as `a = b` or `a > b^2 / a`, the result in the table would then not be a number but TRUE or FALSE.

Is there a function to create such a table in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x <- 1:3
outer(x,x,"+")

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
[2,]    3    4    5
[3,]    4    5    6
```

You can pass other functions to `outer`, e.g.

```
outer(x,x,"==")

outer(x,x,FUN=function(a,b){a > (b^2 / a)})
```